# Сервер отвечает ошибкой:500 ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, typescript, asp.net-core, angular

Хочу сделать магазин одежды на ангуляре и asp, но столкнулся со сложностью отправки данных в бд.
Есть модульная форма для регистрации и авторизации. Первым делом решил реализовать форму регистрации, но произошла ошибка отправки данных:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я новичок в этом деле, так что прилагаю код, ибо уже не знаю в чём проблема ошибки.

User.ts:

```
export class Users{
   id? = "";

   phone = "";

   email = "";

   fio = "";

   address ="";

   password = "";

}
```

user-service.ts:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserServiceService {

  private url = "User";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }
  @Input() public createUser(users: Users): Observable<Users> {
    return this.http.post<Users>(
      `${environment.apiUrl}/${this.url}`,
      users
    );
```

nav-menu.ts:

```
export class NavMenuComponent {

  user:Users =new Users;
  @Output() userUpdated = new EventEmitter<Users>();
  constructor(private superHeroService: UserServiceService) {}
  createnewUser(users: Users) {
    this.superHeroService
      .createUser(users)
      .subscribe((users: Users) => this.userUpdated.emit(users));
  }

}
```

Считываются переменные с input :

```html
<div class="modal-body">
  <input [(ngModel)]="user.email" class="form-control">
  <input [(ngModel)]="user.phone" class="form-control">
  <input [(ngModel)]="user.address" class="form-control">
  <input [(ngModel)]="user.fio" class="form-control">
  <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password" class="form-control"> :
  <input type="password" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Backend:

UserController.cs:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private readonly DataContext _context;

    public UserController(DataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateUser(User user)
        {
            _context.Users.Add(user);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Ok(await _context.Users.ToListAsync());
        }
}
```

DataContext.cs:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users => Set<User>();

}
```

User.cs:
public class User

```
{
    public string? Id = string.Empty;

    public string Phone = string.Empty;

    public string Email = string.Empty;

    public string FIO = string.Empty;

    public string Password = string.Empty;

}
```

Comment: И что вы хотите от нас? Мы же не видим текста ошибок (исключений), произошедших в коде. | В классе `User` сделайте свойства вместо полей. В методе `CreateUser` где стандартная проверка `if (ModelState.IsValid)`?

Comment: Благодарю вас, вы мне помогли починить всё. Дело было в том, что я сделал вместо свойств поля в User.cs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User.cs:

```
public class User
{
    public string? Id { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string FIO { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

}
```